# Connecting between C++ istream/ostream and Java InputStream/OutputStream in JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, iostream

Are there any existing C++/JNI libraries that do the work of marshalling access between a Java `InputStream` and a C++ `istream`, as well as a Java `OutputStream` and a C++ `ostream`? In particular, I want a Java application to be able to pass an `InputStream` or an `OutputStream` into a C++ library that uses `iostreams` as its streaming interface.

If no existing library exists, what is the minimum functionality I need to implement in an `istream`/`ostream` implementation in order to support this?  To make things worse, I will also need to support `seek` and `tell`, although in principle I should be able to use `mark`, `reset`, and `skip` to do what I need.

As these streams can be quite large I do not want to simply load them into a `ByteArray` which then gets turned into a `stringstream` or the like.

Comment: For clarification, what is the data flow here? Are the actual source/sink the Java streams or the C++ streams?

Comment: I thought it was clear already, but I edited the question a bit anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your sources/sinks are the Java objects and that your C++ library needs to read from the Java `InputStream` and write to Java `OutputStream` instances and that you need a facade of C++ IO streams that you can pass down to your C++ parts that will call back for data into your Java objects.

I suggest implementing C++ IO streams facade for the Java streams using the [Boost.Iostreams library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html). Browse the docs and examples. What you want is the [`stream_buffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/generic_streams.html#stream_buffer) and [`stream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/generic_streams.html#stream) classes together with your own implementation of [Sink](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/concepts/sink.html) and [Source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/concepts/source.html) concepts (see also [Device concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/concepts.html#device_concepts) and [`device` class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/generic_streams.html#stream)).

**UPDATE**

To implement seeking you need to implement the [SeekableDevice concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/concepts/seekable_device.html) and provide appropriate tag in your [device's `category`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/traits.html#category_tags).

Comment: I was looking at that, but I didn't see how to add seek/tell functionality into that. Unfortunately, seek/tell are absolutely necessary because most operations require rewinding and some of them require full-on random access.  Of course, no matter what, supporting seek/tell correctly is going to be a world of hurt due to Java's mark/reset concept.

Comment: @fluffy: I have updated the answer with references too SeekableDevice concept.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this and accept if it works for me. :) Disappointing that there aren't any existing libraries to do all this stuff though - you'd think this were a common enough use case...